# in app purchase android

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Делаю встроенные покупки в android.

Добавил в код активити onCreate:

```
String base64EncodedPublicKey;
        base64EncodedPublicKey = "ххх";

        // compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    Log.d("TEST", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                }
                Log.d("TEST", "ALL IS OK " + result);
                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
            }
        });
```

И в класс активити:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle error
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                consumeItem();
                buybutton.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    };

    public void consumeItem() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
            = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {


            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle failure
            } else {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                        mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
            new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                              IabResult result) {

                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        //all is OK
                    } else {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }
            };


    public void buyClick(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
    }
```

Сделал release версию, подписанную моим ключом.
Закачал на реальное устройство, добавил тестовый аккаунт в консоли и на устройстве.
При попытку купить пишет "Необходимо войти в аккаунт Google". Что делать?

Comment: Необходимо войти в аккаунт.

Comment: Вы можете мне помочь с реализацией? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497488/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-inappbilling-%D0%B2-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в альфа-тесте добавить тестировщиков, опубликовать АПК(можно и в альфе), передать им ссылки на приложение, они должны его открыть и принять(что хотят стать тестировщиками). Потом переключиться на эти аккаунты и установить приложение с релизной подписью.
А так же попробуй:

```
List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
skuList.add("some_sku_001");
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, mGotInventoryListener);
```