# Как правильно создать InAppBilling в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Нужно сделать платное отключение рекламы в приложении Android. Всего готово, реклама adMob. Что мне нужно сделать по пунктам, чтобы интегрировать InApp в приложение ?

Находил много отличных друг от друга уроков, поэтому нужно помощь коммунити ruSO.

Comment: Я пользовался вот этими ресурсами. Все получилось. Все работает. 
Ссылка1: https://habrahabr.ru/post/203368/
Ссылка2: https://habrahabr.ru/post/117944/

Comment: @dubok79, спасибо! Почитаю) Скажите, пожалуйста, а Вы не делали временное отключение рекламы: 1мес, 3 мес, 1год. И есть ли в этом смысл ? Поделитесь свои мнением, пожалуйста))

Comment: @dubok79, прочитал обе статьи, но склеить в один рабочий проект не смог. Можете подкинуть реализацию от и до ?

Comment: попробуйте почитать эту ссылку: https://habrahabr.ru/post/233265/

Comment: @dubok79, прочел. В комментариях плохо отзываются о библиотеке. Я бы с удовольствием внедрил родную гугловскую, но не смог сам разобраться в последовательности действий

Comment: Да я бы помог вам, но сам занимался этим больше года назад, а выдернуть из проекта не получается. Что-то там импортировать нужно, что то подключать. А было это еще на Ecplipse, а там все по другому было.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы сами ответить на свой вопрос подробной инструкцией, раз Вы смогли реализовать через стороннюю библиотеку. Делай раз, делай два, делай три. Сам не понимаю, что пишет этот черт гугл, и нахожусь в Вашем положении. Это будет очень полезно, так как все, что есть в русском интернете на эту тему, напоминает беседы на скамейке под луной.

Answer (score 1):

По этой ссылке есть пример(TrivialDrive) и инструкция как интегрировать:
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample
Если в кратце, то:

1. в проекте создать папки
   "\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\" и в последнюю
   скопировать файл IInAppBillingService.aidl, он автоматом сгенерирует
   код
2. перенести в свой проект исходники из папки
   "\TrivialDrive\app\src\main\java\com\example\android\trivialdrivesample\util\"

Comment: Это я уже делал. Что нужно было писать в самом классе `MyFragment`, чтобы осуществлять покупки ?

Comment: необходимо выполнить метод "launchPurchaseFlow", например: mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(activity, SKU_TEST_PURCHASED, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);

Comment: Это, кончено, прекрасно, что Вы знает принцип работы, но мне нужен полный принцип реализации с комментариями. Увы, но я так и не понял гугловский  пример, поэтому и реализовал покупки через стороннюю библиотеку.

Comment: @web_alex - как вы сделали?